# Convergence of the double series $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) x_{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, mobius-function

Let $\sum x_n$ be a power series which behaves sufficiently nicely, for example, absolutely convergent. Can we deduce that the double series
$$
\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) x_{n}
$$
converges *in the sense described below* to zero? From the property of **Mobius function** $\mu$ that $\sum_{d|n} \mu (d)=0$, the only possible limit of this series is zero. But to show that it converges is a bit difficult, since $\mu$ does not necessarily sum nicely to zero in partial sums.

Definition of convergence:
we say that a double series $\sum a_{ij}$ converges to $l$ if for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N>0$ such that for all finite set $I\subseteq \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ satisfying $\{0,1,\ldots, N\}^2 \subseteq I$, we have
$$
\left| \sum_{(i,j)\in I} a_{ij} - l \right|<\epsilon.
$$

In particular, for this question, we have
$$
a_{ij}=\mu(i) x_j \text{ if }i|j,\\
a_{ij}=0 \text{ otherwise. }
$$

Alternatively we can consider the series
$$
\sum_{d, m} \mu(d) x_{md},
$$
where $md$ is the product of $m$ and $d$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) x_{n}= x_1$$ Did you mean $$\sum_{d\ge 1}\mu(d)\sum_{m\ge 1} x_{md}$$ ? If $x_n=O( n^{-r})$ for some $r> 1$, since $\tau(n)=O( n^{(r-1)/2})$ then $$\sum_{n\ge 1}\sum_{d|n} |\mu(d) x_{n}|\le \sum_{n\ge 1}|x_{n}|\tau(n)$$ converges so we can change the order of summation to get that both series are equal.

The double series $\sum_{n,d} \mu(d) x_n$ converges independently of the order of summation (thus to $x_1$) iff it converges absolutely iff $\sum_n |x_n| 2^{\omega(n)}$ converges.

With $$\cases{x_n = k^{-1/4}-(k+1)^{-1/4} \ if \ n= \prod_{p\le k} p\\x_n=0 \ otherwise}$$ and $Lpf$ the largest prime factor we get that $$\sum_{d\ge 1}\mu(d)\sum_{m\ge 1} x_{md}=\sum_{d\ge 1} \mu(d)Lpf(d)^{-1/4}$$ which diverges (proof ?)

Comment: I do mean the double series you mentioned, and thank you for the counterexample. The series involving Lpf at last does seem to be divergent, as the Dirichlet series of $\mu$ with $s=1/4$ diverges, but how can I show rigorously that the last series you give diverges?

Comment: I don't have a proof. $\sum_{d\ge 1} \mu(d)Lpf(d)^{-1/4}$ is not a Dirichlet series because $Lpf(d)$ is not increasing, the Dirichlet series $\sum_{d\ge 1} \mu(d)Lpf(d)^{-1/4} d^{-s}$ is $=-\sum_p p^{-1/4-s}\prod_{q<p}(1-q^{-s})$ for $s > 1$ but this doesn't help much.

Comment: Of course it is not a Dirichlet series...but why is the Lpf series divergent?